# Kentico Navigation Menu

Tags: css, content-management-system, frontend, web-deployment, kentico

I'm working in Kentico 7, and I need to apply a certain type of CSS style to a new "drop-down-menu". The master page shows a certain CSS style for its navigation menu, however, the navigation menu is comprised of repeaters (web parts). This is creating an issue because I now have to add a little more complexity to my navigation menu that the repeaters don't allow. I was able to get the desired navigation menu characteristics by adding the "drop-down-menu" webpart, however, the CSS styling doesn't look anything like it did when using the repeaters. How can I find the CSS that is being used on the repeaters and apply it to the "drop-down-menu"? Thank!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question that we can answer. You have provided some background for the question, but how can we help you without seeing the code? Please edit the question to show the parts of the code that are causing you difficulty. Otherwise the question will be downvoted and eventually deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the blog post about building menus according to Kentico best practices:

http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/best-practices-for-implementing-site-navigation-in-kentico

Standard structure for a hierarchical transformation looks like this:

Header transformation:

```
<ul>
```

Item transformation:

```
<li>
  <a href="{% GetDocumentUrl() %}" title="{% HTMLEncode(DocumentName) %}">{% HTMLEncode(DocumentName) %}</a>
  {^SubLevelPlaceHolder^}
</li>
```

Footer transformation:

```
</ul>
```

This generates a structure like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="/item-1.aspx" title="item 1">item 1</a>  
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="/item-2.aspx" title="item 2">item 2</a>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="/item-2/subitem-1.aspx" title="subitem 1">subitem 1</a> 
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="/item-3.aspx" title="item 3">item 3</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

When you want your menu to reflect properties from **Properties → Navigation** section of a page, you need to implement some logic to your item transformation.
There are following columns in the **CMS_Document** database table reflecting properties from **Navigation** section:

```
[DocumentMenuCaption]
[DocumentMenuStyle]
[DocumentMenuItemImage]
[DocumentMenuItemLeftImage]
[DocumentMenuItemRightImage]
[DocumentMenuJavascript]
[DocumentMenuRedirectUrl]
[DocumentMenuClass]
[DocumentMenuStyleHighlighted]
[DocumentMenuClassHighlighted]
[DocumentMenuItemImageHighlighted]
[DocumentMenuItemLeftImageHighlighted]
[DocumentMenuItemRightImageHighlighted]
[DocumentMenuItemInactive]
```

Let's go through all relevant properties from Navigation section:

**1) Menu caption**

You can specify custom menu caption that differs from the Page name, so you need to check if this property if not empty and in case it's filled out use the caption instead. For finding out if some property is empty or not you can use either `String.IsNullOrEmpty(DocumentMenuCaption)` or `DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()==""` in your macro. In my examples I use the second option:

```
{% HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName) %}
```

Macro checks if there is any **DocumentMenuCaption** specified and if it's not it uses **DocumentName** instead.

**2) Menu actions**

Inactive menu item redirect to URL:

```
{% (DocumentMenuItemInactive && DocumentMenuRedirectUrl.ToString()=="")?"":"href='"+GetDocumentUrl()+"' ") %}
```

Javascript command:

```
{% (DocumentMenuJavascript.ToString()!=""?"onclick=\""+DocumentMenuJavascript+"\" ":"") %}
```

Redirections are natively supported by Kentico already.

**3) Menu design:**

*Menu item style:*

```
{% (DocumentMenuStyle.ToString()!=""?"style='"+DocumentMenuStyle+"' ":"") %}
Menu item CSS class:
class='{% (DocumentMenuClass.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuClass:"DefaultClassOrNothing") %}'
```

*Menu item left image:*

```
{% (DocumentMenuItemLeftImage.ToString()!=""?"<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemLeftImage+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />":"") %}
```

*Menu item image:*

```
{% if (DocumentMenuItemImage.ToString()!="") { "<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemImage+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />"; } %}
```

*Menu item right image:*

```
{% (DocumentMenuItemRightImage.ToString()!=""?"<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemRightImage+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />":"") %}
```

*- highlighted:*
All previous properties have their own - highlighted version. The code name of such property has the Highlighted postfix appended. To find out whether a menu item is highlighted or not, you can call following macro method:

```
IsCurrentDocument()
```

Depending on your needs, you can also make all items on a path to current menu item to be highlighted as well using following method instead:

```
IsDocumentOnSelectedPath()
```

The final Item transformation would look like this:

```
<li {% if (IsCurrentDocument()) { return (DocumentMenuStyleHighlighted.ToString()!=""?"style='"+DocumentMenuStyleHighlighted+"' ":""); } else { return (DocumentMenuStyle.ToString()!=""?"style='"+DocumentMenuStyle+"' ":""); } #%}class='{% if (IsCurrentDocument()) { return (DocumentMenuClassHighlighted.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuClassHighlighted:"DefaultClassOrNothing"); } else { return (DocumentMenuClass.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuClass:"DefaultClassOrNothing"); } #%}'>
  {% if (IsCurrentDocument()) { DocumentMenuItemLeftImageHighlighted.ToString()!=""?"<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemLeftImageHighlighted+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />":"" } else { DocumentMenuItemLeftImage.ToString()!=""?"<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemLeftImage+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />":"" } %}
  <a {% (DocumentMenuJavascript.ToString()!=""?"onclick=\""+DocumentMenuJavascript+"\" ":"") #%}{% ((DocumentMenuItemInactive && DocumentMenuRedirectUrl.ToString()=="")?"":"href='"+GetDocumentUrl()+"' ") #%}title='{% HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName) #%}'>{% if (IsCurrentDocument()) { if (DocumentMenuItemImageHighlighted.ToString()!="") { "<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemImageHighlighted+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />"; } else { HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName); } } else { if (DocumentMenuItemImage.ToString()!="") { "<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemImage+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />"; } else { HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName); } } #%}</a>
  {% if (IsCurrentDocument()) { DocumentMenuItemRightImageHighlighted.ToString()!=""?"<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemRightImageHighlighted+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />":"" } else { DocumentMenuItemRightImage.ToString()!=""?"<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemRightImage+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />":"" } else { DocumentMenuItemRightImage.ToString()!=""?"<img src='"+DocumentMenuItemRightImage+"' alt='"+HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption.ToString()!=""?DocumentMenuCaption:DocumentName)+"' />":"" } %}
  {^SubLevelPlaceHolder^}
</li>
```

Comment: I've found that the "drop-down-menu" web part is doing exactly what I need it to do, however, I can't seem to find its CSS stye properties, nor can I find out how it automatically uses certain elements out of the CMS tree, rather than using all of the elements.

Comment: For example: the main elements may include Home, Visit, About, Announcements, Contact, and Blog. When I add the "drop-down-menu" webpart from the navigation selection, it automatically inserts a nav menu that only includes Visit, About, Announcements, and Contact. Where can I go to find out where it's doing this, where this property is?

Answer (score 1):

For v7, [take a look at this article](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/creating-a-mega-menu-using-hierarchical-transformations) by Kentico Support which talks about building a Mega Menu with a Hierarchical Viewer and hierarchical transformations. Essentially you will build out your navigation with the HTML needed based on the node level, document type and any other conditions you can add into the transformation.

With v8 and newer there is an option to put a placeholder in the transformations to say where the child nodes will go; this feature is not available in v7 and in my opinion is reason enough to upgrade as it can save huge amounts of time.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! I'll dive into it!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article about [Best Practices for Implementing Site Navigation in Kentico](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/best-practices-for-implementing-site-navigation-in-kentico)

For drop down menus you will be better off with Hierarchical menu

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into that.

Comment: Keen in mind @ChrisWestman this solution is for v8 and newer.  Some features of the hierarchical viewer are not available in v7.

Comment: Right. What I've been looking at now is using a standard "drop-down-menu", as it's listed in the navigation webparts. The only issue now is to style it so it matches the repeaters that I need to replace.

Comment: I'd take a look at the article I posted as it is specific to v7 and will get you what you're looking for although it will require some effort and lots of trial and error.